# Assign same dictionary into multiple variable

Tags: python

I'm currently studying Python, and I've encountered something I don't understand. What I want to do is:

1. I have variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and I want to assign a dictionary `k={'sd':'asd', 'we':'qwe'}`, so I typed like this:

```
a=k
b=k
c=k
```

2. And if I edit `a` like, `a['are']='friend'`, I found out that `b` and `c` also has `are` key even though I only edit `a`.

I don't understand cuz I `a`, `b`, and `c` are all different variable, and how they are "linked" each other..? And what should I do for what I supposed to do?

Comment: See also: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

There's only *one* dictionary, referenced by three variables, so making changes to it via any one variable reflects everywhere. You might want to make *copies* of the dictionary.

```
a = k.copy()
b = k.copy()
c = k.copy()
```